# "a specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated" after i joined the device to azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, sharing, file-sharing, passport-azure-ad

"a specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated" after i joined the device to azure active directory

-i can't access our shared folder in our server after i joined the device to azure AD and use office 365 account (Please see click the link below to see the error image for your reference), but if i use local administrator of the device i can access the file server using the credentials with no problem, please note that we don't have an premises active directory or GPO, kindly help me.

[a specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQJ7W.png)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying just "binos" as your username, add hostname with back-slash like so:

```
yourhostname\binos
```

In most cases, this will fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

To access the share, the server would also need to be azure ad joined. which you cannot do with windows server, you would need azure ad Domain Services (AD DS) on azure, then join your file server to that. 
Only Windows 10 devices can be "azure ad-joined devices"

If you don't want to do that, you could create a azure file store, and secure it using your azure ad / rbac, then map that on your devices.. that would probably work too.